# Installing opencv on Ubuntu - can't find libopencv_calib3d

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, opencv

I successfully installed Opencv via

```
sudo apt-get install libcv-dev libcv4 libcvaux-dev libcvaux4 libhighgui-dev libhighgui4 opencv-doc python-opencv
```

But now when I try to use ruby-opencv I keep getting

```
  libopencv_calib3d not found.
```

error

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try also

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-calib3d2.3
```

Add `libopencv-calib3d-dev` if you need to *compile* the Ruby bindings yourself.

Comment: thank you, will try as soon as Amazon gets back from its power outage ))

Comment: getting E: Couldn't find package libopencv-calib3d2.3

Comment: So I upgraded to Precise and 12.04 and installed Opencv2.4 (default for precise is 2.3), now everything works.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 14.04 I had this issue, which was resolved using:

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```